# Laravel: Browser is taking an eternity to load my project

Tags: laravel, wamp

i'm using `Laravel 5.7` and `WampServer` to develop a project thats giving me a weird problem: it is taking an eternity to load up on my browser and I don't know whats going on. I have another Laravel project that works just fine but this one just crashed for one day to another. What can I do in order to fix this? I don't know where to start.

**EDIT 1:** I've commented the next component and my project runs fine. Either way, I can't see a problem in there. Can anybody help me with it?

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center text-uppercase">{{ userEmailNotFound ? 'Ingresa tu correo electrónico' : 'Responde a la siguiente pregunta' }}</div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="input-group mb-3" v-show="userEmailNotFound">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text mdi mdi-email" id="email-addon"></span>
                </div>
                <input v-model="userEmail" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" aria-describedby="email-addon" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import swal2 from '../mixins/swal2'
// this.swalMixin('success', '¡Artículo creado!')

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            userEmail: '',
            userEmailNotFound: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        //
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

When I said "commented" i meant this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{-- <question-password-component></question-password-component> --}}
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Try `xdebug`, enable profiling, so you can get the most long-time part. Or https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: And... What can i do with debugbar exactly? My Laravel application doesn't even load right now?

Comment: Anything in server logs? Or Laravel logs?

Comment: There are is not a single error at storage/logs/

Comment: Also, I'll like to point out that, once I give up and try to close my terminal... It takes quite a long time, it is too slow for me to wait so I kill the process with the administrator.

Comment: I could be wrong but it sounds like you may have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: There is a Vue component creating the problem but i can't see the error. I just edited my question in order to share this component.

Comment: I moved the ternary operator to the ``created()`` and now it works. I don't know why it didn't work like that but it is done now.